# Reorder X variable based on Facet variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm creating a facet grid.  I'm attempting to reverse the order of levels on the x-axis (Context) based on the level of the specified facet variable(.~Order).

(E.g., For Order, if "NFF", then order of Context = "NF", "IF"; if "IFF", then order of Context = "IF", "NF").

**Edit** Data I'm working with:

```
Order <- c("NFF", "NFF", "NFF", "NFF", "IFF", "IFF", "IFF", "IFF")
Concept <- c("BT","BT", "H", "H", "BT", "BT", "H", "H")
Context <- c("NF", "IF", "NF", "IF", "IF", "NF", "IF", "NF")
Mean <- c(3.587, 3.857, 3.467, 3.101, 2.986, 3.965, 3.154, 3.555)
SE <- c(0.13, 0.229, 0.143, 0.251, 0.281, 0.159, 0.251, 0.143)

FlowExp1 <- data.frame(Order, Concept, Context, Mean, SE)
```

What I've attempted so far:

```
FlowExp1$Context <- factor(FlowExp1.3$Context,
                   levels = c("No Friction", "Implied Friction"))

limits <- aes(ymax = Mean + SE, ymin=Mean - SE)
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.5)
cb<- c("dark grey", "grey30")

p <- ggplot(FlowExp1, aes(fill=Concept, y=Mean, x=Context))
p2<- p + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width = .5)


p2 + 
  geom_bar(position=dodge) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=cb, guide = FALSE)+
  geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.25) + 
  ylim(0,5) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Order)
```

This almost works, I just need to reverse the order of Context on the second graph of the facet_grid.

Comment: Please show this to one of your co-workers and see if they can make any sense of this request. Maybe they can help you edit it so the rest of us can read it with understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by creating a dummy variable that is the `interaction` between the variable on the x-axis and the variable you are faceting by,

```
library(ggplot2)

## Use a subset of the diamonds dataset
data(diamonds)
dat <- droplevels(with(diamonds, diamonds[color %in% c("E","I") & 
                                 clarity %in% c("SI2", "SI1"), ]))

## See what it looks like first
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(fill=color, y=carat, x=clarity))
p2 <- p + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.5)
p2 + facet_grid(. ~ cut, scales="free_x")
```

[image]

The goal here is to change the order of clarity (x-axis) in this figure only in the "Premium" facet.

```
## Create a new factor of the interactions between variables of interest
dat$fact <- with(dat, interaction(cut, clarity))

## Change the order of clarity in "Premium" facet only
inds <- levels(dat$fact)
inds[grep("Premium", inds)] <- rev(grep("Premium", inds, value=T))
dat$fact <- factor(dat$fact, levels=inds)

## Plot it
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(fill=color, y=carat, x=fact))
p2 <- p + geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width=0.5)
p2 + facet_grid(. ~ cut, scales="free_x") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels="") + xlab("Clarity")
```

[image]

Notice the order of SI2 and SI1 has switched in the Premium panel.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to reverse x axis ticks labels as well?  I've been searching with no luck.  If not, perhaps grid arrange or something similar will be better than facet for my purposes.

Comment: Ended up using gridExtra.  Much easier to handle the reversal.